# How to make a secondary process continually update a variable through ProcessPoolExecutor in python

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, pyautogui

Well met!

I'm trying to use pyautogui to run some simple checks, I'm attempting to make the main process detect a visual input, then start a sub process that continually updates a shared variable with the Y position of a different image as it moves through the screen until it disappears.

Unfortunately I'm barely a programmer so I keep getting stuck on the execution, so I wanted to ask for help. This is the code I wrote,

```
import pyautogui
import time
import importlib
foobar = importlib.import_module("cv2")
foocat = importlib.import_module("concurrent")
import numpy
import concurrent.futures

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    CheckingInput = executor.submit(CheckPositionInput)
    CheckingImage = executor.submit(CheckPositionImage)

print(XMark, YMark)
print(time.time() - startingtime)

def CheckPositionInput():

    Checked = False
    global XImage, YImage, XMark, YMark, AreaOnScreen
    while not Checked:
        print('Searching')
        if pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('Area.png', confidence=0.8) != None:
            Checked = True
            AreaOnScreen = True
            XMark, YMark = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('Area.png', confidence=0.8)

def CheckPositionImage():
    global XImage, YImage, XMark, YMark, AreaOnScreen
    print('start')
    while not AreaOnScreen:
        print('Waiting')
        while AreaOnScreen:
            if pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('Image.png', confidence=0.6) != None:
                XMark, YMark = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('Image.png', confidence=0.6)
                print(YMark)
                print('Checking')
```

The problems I've run into go from the while loop in `CheckPositionImage` closing and dying after a single loop, to the while loop in `CheckPositionImage` getting stuck and stopping the check position process, and that no matter what I try I can't manage to update the crucial `Ymark` variable properly outside the process.

Comment: When posting a minimal reproducible example, include the import statements as well. As for your question, the child and parent processes don't share memory, so you need to use shared memory if you want them to communicate (in this case you seem to want to communicate the variable values between the two processes). A good resource is here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-between-processes.

Comment: The code is simply not working, it fails down to its very essence. so there's nothing to reproduce.  But I understand that adding the import statements can be important for troubleshooting, so I will add them, thank you. I'll also check the resource you linked, thank you for that as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to understand that global variables are not read/write sharable across multiple processes. A child process *can* possibly inherit such a variable value (depends on what platform you are running) and read its value, but once a process assigns a new value to that variable, this change is not reflected back to any other process. This is because every process runs in its own address space and can only modify its copy of a global variable. You would need to use instead *shared memory* variables created by the main process and passed to its child processes. But let's ignore this fundamental problem for now and assume that global variables were sharable.

If I follow your code correctly, this is what you appear to be doing:

1. The main process submits two tasks to a multiprocessing pool to be processed by worker functions `CheckPositionInput` and `CheckPositionImage` and then waits for both tasks to complete to print out global variables `XMark` and `YMark`, presumably set by the `CheckPositionImage` function.
2. `CheckPositionImage` is *effectively* doing nothing until `CheckPositionInput` sets global variable `AreaOnScreen` to `True`, which only occurs after the call `pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('Area.png', confidence=0.8)` returns a value that is not `None`. When this occurs, `checked` is set to `True` and your loop terminates effectively terminating the task.
3. When varibale `AreaOnScreen` is set to `True` (in step 2. above), function  `CheckPositionImage` finally enters into a loop calling `pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('Image.png', confidence=0.6)`. When this function returns a value that is not `None` a couple of print statements are issued and the loop is re-iterated.

**To the extent that my analysis is correct**, I have a few comments:

1. This `CheckPositionImage` task never ends since variable `AreaOnSCreen` is neither ever reset to `False` nor is a `return` nor `break` statement issued in the loop. I assume this is an oversight and once we are returned a non-`None` value from our call to `pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen`, we should return. My assumption is based on the fact that without this termination occurring, the main process's block beginning with `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:` will never complete (there is am implicit wait for all submitted tasks to complete) and you will therefore never fall through to the subsequent `print` statements.
2. You never initialize variable `startingtime`.
3. Function `CheckPositionInput` sets global variables `XMark` and `YMark`, whose values are never referenced by either the main process or function `pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('Image.png', confidence=0.6)`. What is the point in calling this function a second time with identical arguments to set these variables that are never read?

**You have processes running, but the actual processing is essentially sequential**: The main process does nothing until both child processes it has created end and one child process does nothing useful until the other child process sets a flag when its terminating. I see, therefore, no reason for using multiprocessing at all. Your code could be simply (note that I have renamed variables and functions according to Python's [PEP8 coding conventions](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/):

```py
import pyautogui
import time
# What is the purpose of these next 3 commented-out statements?
#import importlib
#foobar = importlib.import_module("cv2")
#foocat = importlib.import_module("concurrent")

def search_and_check():
    print('Searching...')
    while True:
        if pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('Area.png', confidence=0.8) != None:
            # What is the purpose of this second call, which I have commented out?
            # Note that the values set, i.e. xMark and yMark, are never referenced.
            #xMark, yMark = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('Area.png', confidence=0.8)
            break
    print('Checking...')
    while True:
        result = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('Image.png', confidence=0.6)
        if result != None:
            return result

starting_time = time.time()
xMark, yMark = search_and_check()
print(xMark, yMark)
print(time.time() - starting_time)
```

**Could/should the two different calls to `pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen` be done in parallel?**